# jQuery .load slow reacting after click b

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have some close to load in a div content from another page on click on a menu. This all works, however it's really slow once built in to Wordpress. If I click a link it looks like it's not working - then it shows the content.

Any ideas?

Here is my html:

```
  <nav>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/about/">about</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/kitchen-gallery/">gallery</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/suppliers/">suppliers</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/contact/">contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   </nav>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$(function () {
$("nav ul li a").click(function(event) {
    loadData(this.href + " #content");
    event.preventDefault();
});
});

  function loadData(data) {
  $('#content').load(data, '#content',function(data){
    $.getScript("http://www.mydomain.co.uk/pathtofoler/wp-content/themes/space/js/pe.flare/jquery.pixelentity.flare.min.js");

    $("#post-container").hide();

    $("#content-container").slideDown(600, function() {
        $(".block-content").slideUp(600);
        $('a[data-target="flare"]').peFlareLightbox();

        $("ul.sub li a").click(function(event) {
            loadData(this.href + " #content");
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        $('#close').click(function(){
            $('#content-container').slideUp(600);
        })

    }); 
})
};
```

I can send a working link if needed. I can PM this as don't want it showing in google searches due to the forum. Hope that's ok.

Comment: It's better to inform users the data is being fetched, and then use `success` (inside `load()`) to show the data when it's loaded. The reason of it being slow is the most likely a high overhead the remote script you are calling. You should debug it in the Web Inspector/Firebug and see how long everything takes.

Comment: Why are you loading jquery.pixelentity.flare.min.js inside the loadData function?

Comment: when you say `slow` loading time, it's subjective to the user and variables involved. But I suspect that your fetching an entire page to get a single part of it into your current page which results in unwanted data being transferred which would result in slowness. It would be best if you can post a working link.

Comment: Have you thought about displaying a loading spinner whilst you load and hiding it on load complete? there are loads out there, just stick it in your master page and show/hide when you need...

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're using jquery to slideUp/slideDown the container. An alternative, which may help your problem, would be to use css3 transition or transform. Use JS or JQuery to assign a classname to $('#content-container'). Then handle the animation in your stylesheet with css3.